# hadoop mapreduce issue with pig lower versions to read data from cassandra

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig

I have setup `hadoop1.2.1`, `pig 0.10` and `cassandra 2.0.3`. When I try to read data from `cassandra` it works in local mode but in mapreduce mode I got error like

```
WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child: Error running child
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)  
at org.apache.pig.data.DefaultTuple.get(DefaultTuple.java:156)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [hadoop mapreduce mode issue for reading data from cassandra using pig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569794/hadoop-mapreduce-mode-issue-for-reading-data-from-cassandra-using-pig)

Comment: May be I'll check that Thanks. But I tried with cassandra 1.2.2 it works fine now. But still i cant solve this issue in cassandra 2.0.3.